# Avoiding bodyless abstract methods when implementing an interface - java

Tags: java, interface, methods, abstract

Really annoying when I want to implement an interface for a simple WindowListener but the only way to get the job done is to implement all the methods just to leave all but one bodyless. Looks really ugly and avoidable..

Is there some kind of design pattern that can avoid bodyless implementations in this type of case?

I tried the Strategy/Policy pattern but I just end up with the same bodyless methods, except in more OOP way.

Answer (score 6):

Use a [WindowAdapter](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/awt/event/WindowAdapter.html) and override only methods you need. More on this [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/generalrules.html#eventAdapters).

Comment: Thanks, that was on the tip of my brain! Seriously I remember having learned that a while ago.

Comment: Hmm, this is where the lack of multi-inheritance comes in. I'm extending JFrame, so now I have to declare a dummy class just to extend WindowAdapter and pass it into addWindowListener() which is in my main class. I could have passed this instead and avoided a dummy class which would've been alright if I could extend both JFrame and WindowAdapater..

Comment: @Sam Ismail: This is typically where anonymous classes are used, which incurs relatively little code overhead.

Answer (score 2):

In the API docs of [WindowListener](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/event/WindowListener.html) there is a class [`WindowAdapter`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/event/WindowAdapter.html) mentioned as implementing the interface:

> The methods in this class are empty. This class exists as convenience for creating listener objects.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, for listeners there is often an `AbstractXXXAdapter` that has all of the methods defined (with empty bodies). And then when you use your own listener you just subclass that and implement what you need. Some frameworks provide these, other's don't thus you might have to do it yourself.

Comment: In case of `WindowListener` this is the `WindowAdapter` class

Comment: Thanks, I was not paying attention to which framework they were asking about.